# Dealing with Excel file in Perl

Tags: perl, excel

I have an excel file. It has 5 columns.

```
1st column: URL
2nd column: Pagerank
3rd column: Niche
4th column: Language
5th column: IP
```

There are total 2000 rows.

I want to extract out only those rows where `Niche == Poker` and save it in a new excel file. How can I do that in Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short working example using Spre[adsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/) to read the input file and [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/) to write it out the matched data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;


# Read the input and output filenames.
my $in_filename  = shift;
my $out_filename = shift;


# Simple check for valid arguments.
if ( !$in_filename || !$out_filename ) {
    die( "Usage: poker_extract oldfile.xls newfile.xls\n" );
}

# Create a parser to read the input Excel file.
my $parser      = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $in_workbook = $parser->parse( $in_filename );

# Check for any parse errors.
if ( !defined $in_workbook ) {
    die "Parsing error: ", $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

# Create a writer to store the new Excel data.
my $out_workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new( $out_filename );


# Read the data from the first worksheet (or whichever).
my $in_worksheet  = $in_workbook->worksheet( 0 );
my $out_worksheet = $out_workbook->add_worksheet();
my $out_row       = 0;

# Get the data range for the input worksheet.
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $in_worksheet->row_range();
my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $in_worksheet->col_range();

# Loop over the input rows.
for my $in_row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {

    # Check the cell in the third column.
    my $cell = $in_worksheet->get_cell( $in_row, 2 );

    if ( $cell && $cell->value() eq 'Poker' ) {

        # We have a matched row. Read the rest of the row data.
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            # Get a cell object.
            my $cell = $in_worksheet->get_cell( $in_row, $col );

            # Skip to the next cell if this one is empty.
            next unless $cell;

            # Store the data in the output file.
            $out_worksheet->write( $out_row, $col, $cell->unformatted() );
        }

        $out_row++;
    }
}


__END__
```

Answer (score 4):

To read/parse Excel files you can use:

- `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` for "old" Excel file with `` suffix (Excel 97-2003)
- `Spreadsheet-XLSX` for new Excel file with `.xlsx` suffix (Excel 2007+)

And to write another excel file, once you have extracted the data you want, either:

- `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` for "old" Excel file with `.xls` suffix (Excel 97-2003)

  The `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` documentation contains many examples and the [developper site](http://groups.google.com/group/spreadsheet-writeexcel) has even more info.
- `Excel::Writer::XLSX` for new Excel file with `.xlsx` suffix (Excel 2007+)

Answer (score 0):

[How can I read Excel files in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134707/how-can-i-read-excel-files-in-perl)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pexcel/

These will probably get you started